# ServiceWorker: Return from Cache, Get from Network, Copy to Cache, Return Again

Tags: service-worker

I've already designed a service worker that:

1. Checks the cache first and if found, returns to the browser
2. Checks the network for new content and updates the cache
3. Displays an offline template if the desired page is not found in the cache and there is no network response.

   ```
    self.addEventListener('fetch',(event) => {
        console.log('SW fetch event.', event.request.method, event.request.url);
        if(!/\/recaptcha\/|(\/(([a-z]{2,3})(-[a-z0-9]{2,3})?)\/user\/)/i.test(event.request.url)){
            event.respondWith(
                caches.open(cacheName).then(cache => {
                    return cache.match(event.request).then(response => {
                        const fetchPromise = fetch(event.request).then(networkResponse => {
                            if(networkResponse.status === 404) {
                                return networkResponse;
                            }
                            cache.put(event.request, networkResponse.clone());
                            return networkResponse;
                        });
                        return response || fetchPromise;
                    }).catch(function() {
                        const regex = /\/(([a-z]{2,3})(-[a-z0-9]{2,3})?)\//i;
                        const lng = event.request.url.match(regex);
                        const searchForThis = '/' + lng[1] + '/examples/offline.html';
                        return caches.match(searchForThis);
                    })
                })
            );
        } else {
            event.respondWith(fetch(event.request));
        }
    });
   ```

I'm trying to add some funtionality to the network responce so that its also returned to the user after saving to the cache but I can't get it to work properly yet.  Is it even possible to return a responce twice?

```
    self.addEventListener('fetch',(event) => {
        console.log('SW fetch event.', event.request.method, event.request.url);
        if(!/\/recaptcha\/|(\/(([a-z]{2,3})(-[a-z0-9]{2,3})?)\/user\/)/i.test(event.request.url)){
            event.respondWith(
                caches.open(cacheName).then(cache => {
                    cache.match(event.request).then(response => {
                        return response;
                    }).then(asdf => {
                        fetch(event.request).then(response => {
                            if(response.status !== 404) {
                                cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
                                return response;
                            }
                        })
                    }).catch(function() {
                        const regex = /\/(([a-z]{2,3})(-[a-z0-9]{2,3})?)\//i;
                        const lng = event.request.url.match(regex);
                        const searchForThis = '/' + lng[1] + '/examples/offline.html';
                        return caches.match(searchForThis);
                    })
                })
            );
        } else {
            event.respondWith(fetch(event.request));
        }
    });
```